# How to fix NaN output in Math Equation while using the content numbers in txt file in Node Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, readfile, nodejs-stream

I try to Use the Readlines in Node js to read the line with numbers of the text file to use them in Math equation But the output is NaN

output:
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
soon....

```
test.txt content:

5
5
3 1 2 6 4
6
2 1 3 2 4 3
4
7 9 3 1
2
1 1000
3
100 150 200
```

Here is the code NodeJs:

```js
const lineReader = require('line-reader');
lineReader.eachLine('test.txt', function(line) {
   function comp(a, b) {
      return a-b;
   }
   function solve(n, arr) {
      arr.sort(comp);
      var ans = 1000;
      for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
         ans = Math.min(ans, arr[i]-arr[i-1]);
      return ans;
   }

   var t = Number(line);
   while (t--) {
      var n = Number(line);
      var arr = line.split(' ').map(Number);
      console.log(n);
      console.log(solve(n, arr));
   }
});
```

Comment: Please debug your code. What is the value of `line`? Why are you doing `Number(line)`?

Comment: the value of line is the content of text file which is in the example above 5
5
3 1 2 6 4
6
2 1 3 2 4 3
4
7 9 3 1
2
1 1000
3
100 150 200

Comment: The `eachLine` function already takes care of iterating through the line of `test.txt` (as its name implies). So there's no need to implement your own looping logic with the `while` loop.